# getting IHTMLStyle3 from the Dom of HtmlElement in IE

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I've got a System.Windows.Form.WebBrowser control on a form. I navigate that browser object to a url.

Once the page has finished loading, I'd like to analyse various aspects of the page that loaded.

In particular I'm interested to see the attribute 'writingMode' which is found on the IHTMLStyle3 interface.

Something like:

```
public void MyMethod(HtmlElement element)
    {
        IHTMLElement2 element2 = element.DomElement as IHTMLElement2;
        IHTMLStyle3 style3 = element2.currentStyle as IHTMLStyle3;

        string writingMode = style3.writingMode;
    ...
```

The problem is, the style3 value is null. I assume this means IHTMLElement2.currentStyle doesn't support IHTMLStyle3.

I've tried also tried casting IHTMLELement.style. But while that does cast happily as IHTMLStyle3 it doesn't seem to contain the style as it's been applied to the Html element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, I believe you need to get the [`IHTMLElement2.currentStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa703980(VS.85).aspx) property as the regular `style` property is the inline style only. This difference is indicated in the remarks for [`IHTMLElement2.currentStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa703980(VS.85).aspx):

> The values returned by the properties
>   of the IHTMLStyle and
>   IHTMLCurrentStyle interfaces differ
>   when the style of an object is not set
>   inline. For example, if the author of
>   a Web page sets the color property of
>   a paragraph to red only through a
>   linked or embedded style sheet, and
>   not inline, then the
>   IHTMLCurrentStyle::color property
>   returns the value red, and the
>   IHTMLStyle::get_color property does
>   not return a value. However, if the
>   author specifies the value of the
>   color property inline, as in the
>   following example, both the
>   IHTMLCurrentStyle::color and
>   IHTMLStyle::get_color properties
>   return the value red.

[`currentStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa703980(VS.85).aspx) provides a [`IHTMLCurrentStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa704104(VS.85).aspx) interface, which when queried for [`IHTMLCurrentStyle2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752724(VS.85).aspx) will give you [`writingMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa704098(VS.85).aspx) as you require.

Comment: - silly me I was trying to cast currentStyle as an HTMLStyle3 - I should have been casting it as an HTMLCurrentStyle2!