# How can I get all the visual attributes of a text in a HtmlElement inside a WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, .net, browser

I just need exactly those visual attributes (font, size, color, etc.) that the WebBrowser itself use to render the text. They have to be somewhere otherwise the WebBrowser wouldn't know how to show the text.

Comment: I just found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa704079(v=VS.85).aspx but this "Address of a pointer to a variable of type IDispatch interface that receives a zero-based array of attributes applied to the object." doesn't help me much at all. Have no idea what am I getting back after calling that funciton.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586704/getting-ihtmlstyle3-from-the-dom-of-htmlelement-in-ie

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [HtmlElement.Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.style.aspx) - it's a list of CSS styles.  You can get HtmlElements from the HtmlDocument (e.g. document.Links gives you all the links).  Also, you should only get the HtmlDocument once the browser.DocumentCompleted event fires.